# Changing the formatting of equation numbers

Tags: formatting, equations, numbering

How can I change equation numbering so that the chapter number is outside the parenthesis like this:

> 1(1)

instead of

> (1.1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to redefine `\tagform@` from `amsmath` (to remove the outer parentheses) and `\theequation` (to add them in the desired location):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand\theequation{\thechapter(\arabic{equation})}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\eqref{eq:test}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a=b.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please note that this removes the code that causes the equation number (and parentheses) to remain upright in italic environments, as in theorems.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hmmmm... I don't think my code removes this feature, or am I missing something? This example code shows the number and parantheses upright in a theorem-like structure: `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thechapter(\arabic{equation})}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\ref{eq:test}
\begin{theo}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a=b.
\end{equation}
\end{theo}
\end{document}`

Comment: the example you give does work.  however, it's not what i meant.  what i meant was having the `\ref{...}` *as part of* the theorem text, say a reference in the theorem to a numbered equation that's outside the theorem statement.  when that happens, the reference is italic, not upright.

Comment: @barbarabeeton ah, I see. This, however, is not due to my code; `\ref` behaves like that; on the other hand, `\eqref` (which should be used here instead of `\ref`, anyway) will still produce the reference in upright font. I updated my answer to change `\ref` for `\eqref`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\renewcommand\theequation{\thechapter(\arabic{equation})}
```

Comment: this has produced the following : (12(1)). How can I remove the outside parenthesis so as it looks like this: 12(1)?

Comment: If you are using amsmath see Gonzalo's answer. Questions should _always_ have a complete small document that shows the problem. If you are not using amsmath the `\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont \normalcolor \theequation}}` is the standard definition with `()` removed