# Simple equation editing

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

I am writing a simple equation in my thesis:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
y &= x^{k}\\
\log(y) &= \log(x^{y})\\
\log(y) &= y\log(x)\\
\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)} &= y
\end{align}
\end{equation}
```

It works perfectly. However, `LaTeX` numbers it as `1.1` instead of `1`. How could I easily correct it? Thank you!

Comment: What documentclass are you using? By the way, remove the outer `equation` environment, which does nothing good.

Comment: @Johnathan: The numbering is 'driven' by the documentclass here, most likely. You could kick out, however, for example, using `chngcntr` package

Comment: What's the `\documentclass` line in your document?

Comment: @egreg Hi! It is "report" However, I realized that 1.1 is better than 1 because it indicate the chapter number as well. :)

Comment: Please post a complete MWE.

Comment: @Johnathan: Your calculation is either wrong or they are typos ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The `report` class uses `chapter.equation` numbering, enclosed by parentheses.

If the equation number should be used alone without referring to the chapter number, then `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}` can be used. It requires `chngcntr` package, however.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}



\begin{align}
y &= x^{k}\\
\log(y) &= \log(x^{k})\\
\log(y) &= k\log(x)\\
\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)} &= k
\end{align}


% Now kick out the chapter number
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}


\begin{align}
y &= x^{k}\\
\log(y) &= \log(x^{k})\\
\log(y) &= k\log(x)\\
\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)} &= k
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer based on [another answer on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122179/52417) and upon [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer)'s [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253041/52417). There are many other useful points on [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122177/changing-the-formatting-of-equation-numbers) too.

[image]

```
%pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{align}
y &= x^{k}\\
\log(y) &= \log(x^{y})\\
\log(y) &= y\log(x)\\
\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)} &= y
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This method breaks down starting at chapter 2, since the equation numbers will continue to be reset (to zero!) at the start of each chapter. Presumably, though, the OP would like the equation numbers *not* to be reset.