# Show Equation number in colored box without brackets

Tags: equations, tcolorbox

In the attached code, I would like to get the equation number to show up boxed like this:[image]

instead of the normal brackets "()".

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}
\tcbset{myformula/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
  colframe=ocre,
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  highlight math style={
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
    colframe=red.
    }
  }
}

\newenvironment{spread}[1]{%
  \advance\jot#1% indeed
  }{%
\ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is how it all began}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align,myformula]
LT~&\approx~\frac{400}{F_{c}}(1-log_{10}|\Delta F|)\\
\Delta F~&=~\frac{Frequency~Tolerance}{Frequency~Jump}\nonumber
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the internal `\tagform@`; the original definition is

```
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
```

and I used a `\fcolorbox`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\fcolorbox{ocre}{mygray}{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces\textcolor{ocre}{#1}\unskip\@@italiccorr}}}
\makeatother
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\tcbset{myformula/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
  colframe=ocre,
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  highlight math style={
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
    colframe=red.
    }
  },
}

\newenvironment{spread}[1]{%
  \advance\jot#1% indeed
  }{%
\ignorespacesafterend
}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\fcolorbox{ocre}{mygray}{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces\textcolor{ocre}{#1}\unskip\@@italiccorr}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is how it all began}
\section{Introduction}

A cross-reference using \verb!\ref!: \ref{equ:test}\par\noindent
A cross-reference using \verb!\eqref!: \eqref{equ:test}
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align,myformula]
LT~&\approx~\frac{400}{F_{c}}(1-log_{10}|\Delta F|) \label{equ:test}\\
\Delta F~&=~\frac{Frequency~Tolerance}{Frequency~Jump}\nonumber
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize that you posted, so I have deleted my (duplicate) answer.  I apparently used your nice solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122177/changing-the-formatting-of-equation-numbers.  +1

Comment: how do you give a cross-reference to such an equation?  (neither `\ref` not `\eqref` seems to work, but that could be because i don't have easy access to the latest versions of all the packages.)  would be helpful if you added an example.

Comment: @barbarabeeton both `\ref`` and `\eqref` work. The latter will produce the reference in a frame like the one used for the tags. I'll add an example.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I spoke too soon! `\eqref` produced the proper refeernce inside the framed box but on a new line, so now I changed to a simple `\fcolorbox` which gives better results for `\eqref`. I updated the code with an example of cross-references.

Comment: @Joe You're welcome. Due to a little problem with `\eqref` using the `\tcbox` approach I changed the code to use nos a `\fcolorbox` which behaves as expected. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: thanks!  (always like to see little things like this tidied up.)  gets my vote.

Comment: Excellent work...as usual!  Thanks, Gonzalo!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution with `mathtools` and its `\newtagform` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtagform{boxed}[\fboxrule=0.6pt\fcolorbox{ocre}{ocre!15!}]{\color{ocre}}{}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}
\tcbset{myformula/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
  colframe=ocre,
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  highlight math style={
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
    colframe=red.
    }
  }
}

\newenvironment{spread}[1]{%
  \advance\jot#1% indeed
  }{%
\ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is how it all began}
\section{Introduction}
\usetagform{boxed}
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align,myformula]
LT~&\approx~\frac{400}{F_{c}}(1-log_{10}|\Delta F|)\label{coloureq}\\
\Delta F~&=~\frac{Frequency~Tolerance}{Frequency~Jump}\nonumber
\end{tcolorbox}

\ref{coloureq}

\eqref{coloureq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you extend the example to show how `\ref` and `\eqref` would be used?

Comment: @barbara beeton: Done, milady!

Comment: With this approach, how would you change the color of the equation number text to ocre in the equation environment?

Comment: In the first pair of empty braces (where usually one puts an opening bracket or parenthesis). See my updated answer.

Comment: You're welcome. 'Twas a pleasure to help.